# Read in and manipulate multiple external SVG files

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js

I have several external SVG files (various shapes that are either paths and polygons) that I want to present. For each shape, I want to present them in a random location and in a different stroke color.

I can successfully read *one* in at a time using `d3.xml()`, change its attributes, etc.

```
var sampleSVG = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300);  

var shapes = ["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes-24.svg", 
          "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes-23.svg"];

d3.xml("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes-24.svg", "image/svg+xml", 
       function(xml) {
             sampleSVG.node().appendChild(xml.documentElement);

             var innerSVG = sampleSVG.select("svg");

             innerSVG
                 .select("*")//selects whatever the shape is, be it path or polygon
                 .attr("transform", "translate("+Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)+","+Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)+") scale(.3)")
                 .attr("stroke", "purple");
      });
```

What's the best way to read in multiple external files from my array? And how can I manipulate the position and attributes of each file independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) library from the D3.js author to wait for all files to return before rendering the imported svg. See example below.

```js
var width = 300, height = 300;
var sampleSVG = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr( {width: width, height: height} );

var shapes = [
  { url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes-24.svg", color: 'purple' },
  { url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes-23.svg", color: 'red' }
];

var q = queue();
shapes.forEach(function(shape) { 
  q.defer(d3.xml, shape.url, "image/svg+xml"); 
});

q.awaitAll(function(error, results) { 
  sampleSVG.selectAll('g.shape').data(shapes)
    // g tag is created for positioning the shape at random location
    .enter().append('g').attr('class', 'shape')  
    .attr('transform', function() {
      return 'translate(' + Math.random()*(width-50) + ',' + Math.random()*(height-50) + ')'
    })
    .each(function(d,i) {
      // the loaded svg file is then appended inside the g tag
      this.appendChild(results[i].documentElement);
      d3.select(this).select('svg').select("*")
        .attr("transform", "scale(0.2)")
        .attr("stroke", function() { return d.color; });
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to edit each shape individually, say setting the stroke color a different color for each shape?

Comment: Great, thanks -- are the shapes then treated as a class of objects (".shape") that I can select and further manipulate once they are loaded (e.g. something like ```sampleSVG.selectAll(".shape").transition().attr("stroke", "black");``` to turn them all black [note that this doesn't work])

Comment: You'd have to make the selector like this: `sampleSVG.selectAll(".shape svg *").transition().attr("stroke", "black");`

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem work when I add it after the ```awaitAll``` function -- here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xzc0Lgf/7/

Comment: we're getting further off course from the original question, but... you can't put it outside the awaitAll function because it will execute in the wrong order. The execution of the awaitAll code is asynchronous based on when the files come back from the request.